# What is the distribution of the difference between two Bernoulli distributions?

Tags: probability, random-variables, binomial-distribution

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$ both Bernoulli distributed with the same parameter.

I assume their difference would be binomial distributed but is it so ?

If not how can I come to a conclusion ?

Comment: Which values $Z=X-Y$ can take ? See the elementary corresponding events, for example, $Z=0 \ \iff \ ((X=0)$&$(Y=0))$ or $((X=1)$&$(Y=1))$. Can you associate a probability with this event ?

Comment: Clearly not binomial because the difference can be negative.